# When I update a hosted paypal button's price via BMUpdateButton the inventory data is destroyed

Tags: curl, paypal

When I update a hosted paypal button's price via BMUpdateButton the inventory data is destroyed.  I believe this is due to the loss of the optional item ID data, which is not optional when it comes to tracking inventory.

I'm unable to find an Item ID field in the BMUpdateButton api docs
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMUpdateButton_API_Operation_NVP/

So am I supposed to do the following?

1) BMGetInventory   get inventory and put it in a variable

2) BMUpdateButton   update the hosted buttons price while destroying my inventory data

3) BMSetInventory   restore my inventory data

I'd much rather just call BMUpdateButton without destroying my hosted buttons inventory data in the first place.

Here's the BMUpdateButton call that I'm making via cURL

curl https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp \ -s \ --insecure \ -d USER=itsme.com \ -d PWD=111111 \ -d SIGNATURE=john hancock \ -d VERSION=124.0  \ -d METHOD=BMUpdateButton \ -d HOSTEDBUTTONID=someid \ -d BUTTONTYPE=CART \ -d BUTTONSUBTYPE=PRODUCTS \ -d L_BUTTONVAR0=item_name=my+product1 \ -d L_BUTTONVAR1=amount=100.00